# How to transform an array into an object with "n" arrays?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Good afternoon,

I have two arrays. One that has **all values​​**, and another that has **identifiers** that I want to filter the first array, and separate the values ​​in an object.

Example:

**ARRAY WITH ALL THE VALUES**

```
const ArrayTodosOsValores = [
  {
    "ric": "B3SA3.SA",
    "category": 3,
    "categoryString": "Equity",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "B3 BRASIL BALCAO ORD BAG",
    "ticker": "B3SA3",
    "isin": "BRB3SAACNOR6",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "BOV",
    "country": "BR",
    "instrType": 12,
    "ricRoot": "0 # .BVSP",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
  {
    "ric": "BBAS3.SA",
    "category": 3,
    "categoryString": "Equity",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "BANCO DO BRASIL ORD",
    "ticker": "BBAS3",
    "isin": "BRBBASACNOR3",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "BOV",
    "country": "BR",
    "instrType": 12,
    "ricRoot": "0 # .BVSP",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
  {
    "ric": "1ZEG1",
    "category": 1,
    "categoryString": "Derivatives",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "ETHANOL FEB1",
    "ticker": "EH",
    "isin": "",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "CBT",
    "country": "US",
    "instrType": 9,
    "ricRoot": "0 # 1ZE:",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
  {
    "ric": "1ZEG9",
    "category": 1,
    "categoryString": "Derivatives",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "ETHANOL FEB9",
    "ticker": "EH",
    "isin": "",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "CBT",
    "country": "US",
    "instrType": 9,
    "ricRoot": "0 # 1ZE:",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
]
```

**ARRAY OF IDENTIFIERS**

```
const arrayIdentifiers = ["0 # .BVSP", "0 # 1ZE:"]
```

How to do the ***ArrayAllSettings*** to be filtered through the *ricRoot* property, with the values ​​of ***arrayIdentifiers***, resulting in the following object:

```
const result = {
  0 # .BVSP: [
  {
    "ric": "B3SA3.SA",
    "category": 3,
    "categoryString": "Equity",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "B3 BRASIL BALCAO ORD BAG",
    "ticker": "B3SA3",
    "isin": "BRB3SAACNOR6",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "BOV",
    "country": "BR",
    "instrType": 12,
    "ricRoot": "0 # .BVSP",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
  {
    "ric": "BBAS3.SA",
    "category": 3,
    "categoryString": "Equity",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "BANCO DO BRASIL ORD",
    "ticker": "BBAS3",
    "isin": "BRBBASACNOR3",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "BOV",
    "country": "BR",
    "instrType": 12,
    "ricRoot": "0 # .BVSP",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  }],
  0 # 1ZE: [
  {
    "ric": "1ZEG1",
    "category": 1,
    "categoryString": "Derivatives",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "ETHANOL FEB1",
    "ticker": "EH",
    "isin": "",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "CBT",
    "country": "US",
    "instrType": 9,
    "ricRoot": "0 # 1ZE:",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
  {
    "ric": "1ZEG9",
    "category": 1,
    "categoryString": "Derivatives",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "ETHANOL FEB9",
    "ticker": "EH",
    "isin": "",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "CBT",
    "country": "US",
    "instrType": 9,
    "ricRoot": "0 # 1ZE:",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
 ]
}
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can the identifiers be in arbitrary parts of the array of objects you are filtering. If not you could just use the filter function: `array.filter(el => {return arrayIdentifiers.member(el.ricRoot)});`

Comment: You can make use of hashmap of Key as ricRoot value and value as the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create new properties by filtering the values. With (upcoming) [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
var array = [{ ric: "B3SA3.SA", category: 3, categoryString: "Equity", arcCode: "", description: "B3 BRASIL BALCAO ORD BAG", ticker: "B3SA3", isin: "BRB3SAACNOR6", cusip: "", exchange: "BOV", country: "BR", instrType: 12, ricRoot: "0 # .BVSP", hasChain: true, useChain: false, identifierTypeFound: "Ric", historyMonths: 3 }, { ric: "BBAS3.SA", category: 3, categoryString: "Equity", arcCode: "", description: "BANCO DO BRASIL ORD", ticker: "BBAS3", isin: "BRBBASACNOR3", cusip: "", exchange: "BOV", country: "BR", instrType: 12, ricRoot: "0 # .BVSP", hasChain: true, useChain: false, identifierTypeFound: "Ric", historyMonths: 3 }, { ric: "1ZEG1", category: 1, categoryString: "Derivatives", arcCode: "", description: "ETHANOL FEB1", ticker: "EH", isin: "", cusip: "", exchange: "CBT", country: "US", instrType: 9, ricRoot: "0 # 1ZE:", hasChain: true, useChain: false, identifierTypeFound: "Ric", historyMonths: 3 }, { ric: "1ZEG9", category: 1, categoryString: "Derivatives", arcCode: "", description: "ETHANOL FEB9", ticker: "EH", isin: "", cusip: "", exchange: "CBT", country: "US", instrType: 9, ricRoot: "0 # 1ZE:", hasChain: true, useChain: false, identifierTypeFound: "Ric", historyMonths: 3 }],
    identifiers = ["0 # .BVSP", "0 # 1ZE:"],
    result = Object.fromEntries(
        identifiers.map(k => [k, array.filter(o => Object.values(o).includes(k))])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var array = [{ ric: "B3SA3.SA", category: 3, categoryString: "Equity", arcCode: "", description: "B3 BRASIL BALCAO ORD BAG", ticker: "B3SA3", isin: "BRB3SAACNOR6", cusip: "", exchange: "BOV", country: "BR", instrType: 12, ricRoot: "0 # .BVSP", hasChain: true, useChain: false, identifierTypeFound: "Ric", historyMonths: 3 }, { ric: "BBAS3.SA", category: 3, categoryString: "Equity", arcCode: "", description: "BANCO DO BRASIL ORD", ticker: "BBAS3", isin: "BRBBASACNOR3", cusip: "", exchange: "BOV", country: "BR", instrType: 12, ricRoot: "0 # .BVSP", hasChain: true, useChain: false, identifierTypeFound: "Ric", historyMonths: 3 }, { ric: "1ZEG1", category: 1, categoryString: "Derivatives", arcCode: "", description: "ETHANOL FEB1", ticker: "EH", isin: "", cusip: "", exchange: "CBT", country: "US", instrType: 9, ricRoot: "0 # 1ZE:", hasChain: true, useChain: false, identifierTypeFound: "Ric", historyMonths: 3 }, { ric: "1ZEG9", category: 1, categoryString: "Derivatives", arcCode: "", description: "ETHANOL FEB9", ticker: "EH", isin: "", cusip: "", exchange: "CBT", country: "US", instrType: 9, ricRoot: "0 # 1ZE:", hasChain: true, useChain: false, identifierTypeFound: "Ric", historyMonths: 3 }],
    identifiers = ["0 # .BVSP", "0 # 1ZE:"],
    result = Object.assign(
        {},
        ...identifiers.map(k => ({ [k]: array.filter(o => Object.values(o).includes(k)) }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the reduce() function and filtering the source arrays as following:

```js
const ArrayTodosOsValores = [
  {
    "ric": "B3SA3.SA",
    "category": 3,
    "categoryString": "Equity",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "B3 BRASIL BALCAO ORD BAG",
    "ticker": "B3SA3",
    "isin": "BRB3SAACNOR6",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "BOV",
    "country": "BR",
    "instrType": 12,
    "ricRoot": "0 # .BVSP",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
  {
    "ric": "BBAS3.SA",
    "category": 3,
    "categoryString": "Equity",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "BANCO DO BRASIL ORD",
    "ticker": "BBAS3",
    "isin": "BRBBASACNOR3",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "BOV",
    "country": "BR",
    "instrType": 12,
    "ricRoot": "0 # .BVSP",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
  {
    "ric": "1ZEG1",
    "category": 1,
    "categoryString": "Derivatives",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "ETHANOL FEB1",
    "ticker": "EH",
    "isin": "",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "CBT",
    "country": "US",
    "instrType": 9,
    "ricRoot": "0 # 1ZE:",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
  {
    "ric": "1ZEG9",
    "category": 1,
    "categoryString": "Derivatives",
    "arcCode": "",
    "description": "ETHANOL FEB9",
    "ticker": "EH",
    "isin": "",
    "cusip": "",
    "exchange": "CBT",
    "country": "US",
    "instrType": 9,
    "ricRoot": "0 # 1ZE:",
    "hasChain": true,
    "useChain": false,
    "identifierTypeFound": "Ric",
    "historyMonths": 3
  },
];

const arrayIdentifiers = ["0 # .BVSP", "0 # 1ZE:"]

const result = arrayIdentifiers.reduce((acc, arrayIdentifier) => {
  acc[arrayIdentifiers] = ArrayTodosOsValores.filter(arr => arr.ricRoot === arrayIdentifier);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```